# Combinatorics problem involving series summation

Tags: combinatorics

Can you give a combinatorial proof of $1\cdot1! + 2\cdot2! ....+ (n-1)(n-1)! = n!-1$

Comment: What things have you tried in order to solve this problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried this problem as recognizing r.r! as selection of one of the r objects and their permutations then I tried to think of situation when I will do this. Consider a function from a set A to B where B has r elements and out of all the functions I want a particular pre image to be deleted. This can be done in r ways. But I have no idea how to go further.

Answer (score 6):

All permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ objects (except the identity) can be obtained first swapping $k$ with its desired value and then permuting the lower $k-1$ objects, where $k$ (with $2\le k\le n$) is uniquely determined as the highest non-fixed position.

Comment: Thanks for answering can you please elaborately. This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tree diagram to explain the permutation of ${1,2,3}:$
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the tree diagram?

Answer (score -1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\cdot i !=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i+1-1)\cdot i !=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i+1)\cdot i! -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i !=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i+1)! -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i !=\sum_{i=2}^{n}i !-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i !=n!-1!=n!$$

Comment: The last equality fails and is probably some typo. More important objection: this is not a combinatorial proof.