# Evaluate: $\frac{1}{(1+1)!} + \frac{2}{(2+1)!}+...+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$ using combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

Evaluate    $\frac{1}{(1+1)!} + \frac{2}{(2+1)!}+...+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$.  This is from a combinatorics textbook so I'd like a combinatorial proof.  I find doing this kind of problem difficult especially when you have to sum - I don't know how to construct a sensible analogy using the addition principle.

Similar question that appears just before this question in the text: [Combinatorics problem involving series summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334537/combinatorics-problem-involving-series-summation)

Comment: I'm not sure whether a combinatoric proof can sum those fractions, but induction shows the sum is $1-1/(n+1)!$.

Comment: @J.G. I linked a similar problem maybe that will help... (didn't help me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider a uniformly at random selected permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,n,n+1\}$.

The probability that $2$ appears before $1$ is $\frac{1}{(1+1)!}$

Given that this does not occur, then $1$ and $2$ appear in the correct order.  The probability then that $3$ appears before at least one of $2$ or $1$ as well as $1$ and $2$ appearing in the correct order is $\frac{2}{(2+1)!}$.

Given that this does not occur, then $1,2,3$ all appear in the correct order.  The probability then that $4$ appears before at least on of $3,2,1$ and $1,2,3$ all appearing in the correct order is $\frac{3}{(3+1)!}$...

...

Given that this does not occur, then $1,2,3,\dots,n$ all appear in the correct order.  The probability then that $n+1$ appears before at least one of $n,n-1,\dots,3,2,1$ and $1,2,3\dots,n$ all appear in the correct order is $\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$

Given that this does not occur, then $1,2,3,\dots,n,n+1$ all appear in the correct order.  This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

Note that these are all mutually exclusive and exhaustive events, so they add up to equal $1$.  Note further that the sum you are interested in is the sum of all of the events except the last one.  We have then

$$\frac{1}{(1+1)!}+\frac{2}{(2+1)!}+\dots+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

---

Rephrased, by multiplying the expression by $(n+1)!$, consider partitioning the permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ based on the smallest number $k$ such that $1,2,\dots,k$ appear out of order.

That is to say, if $k$ is the smallest number such that $1,2,\dots,k$ appear out of order then $1,2,\dots,k-1$ must appear in order while $k$ does not appear after $1,2,\dots,k-1$.  To count how many permutations satisfy this condition first pick the spaces that $1,2,\dots,k-1,k$ occupy simultaneously and then pick which of those positions $k$ occupies noting that it cannot be the last.  $1,2,\dots,k-1$ appear in their normal order in the remaining selected positions.  Then all other elements are distributed among the other spaces.  This occurs in

$$\binom{n+1}{k}(k-1)(n+1-k)!=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!}(k-1)(n+1-k)!=\frac{k-1}{k!}(n+1)!$$

which you should recognize as following the sequence $0,\frac{1}{2!},\frac{2}{3!},\frac{3}{4!},\frac{4}{5!},\dots$ with the additional factor of $(n+1)!$ which we introduced earlier, otherwise mimicking the desired sum.

By including also the additional case of the identity permutation, the above forms a partition of the permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$.  It follows that their respective totals add up to $(n+1)!$.

By removing the identity permutation as well as dividing by the factor of $(n+1)!$ that we introduced, this yields the desired identity

$$\frac{1}{(1+1)!}+\frac{2}{(2+1)!}+\dots+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: Hello can you clarify what you mean by the last part: "based on the smallest number k such that 1,2,…,k appear out of order."

Comment: @helios321 Added more details.  If you are just having difficulty understanding the phrasing I used, perhaps an example will help.  $\color{red}{1}5\color{blue}{4}\color{red}{2}6\color{red}{3}$ is an example of a permutation where $\color{blue}{4}$ is the smallest number which occurs out of order since $\color{red}{123}$ appear in the correct order.  By "appearing in the correct order" that is not to say they are adjacent, but merely that $1$ appears before $2$, that $2$ appears before $3$, etc...

Comment: Thanks I figured it out now.  Interesting it seems the expression multiplied by $(n+1)!$ is the same as in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334537/combinatorics-problem-involving-series-summation, both equal $(n+1)!-1$, but the other is counted by fixing the position.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Notice that$$\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k+1)-1}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}.$$

Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right)=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), which [are widely used in combinatorics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Count-Introduction-Combinatorics-Applications/dp/3319355082/):
$$a_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$$
which is the same as
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$
with generating function
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n}\color{red}{a_n}x^n
=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}\left(a_{n-1}+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}\right)x^n=\\
a_0+x\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}x^n=\\
a_0+xf(x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!}x^n-\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^n=\\
a_0+xf(x)+\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\right)'-\frac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=\\
a_0+xf(x)+\left(e^x-1-x\right)'-\frac{1}{x}\left(e^x-1-x\right)=\\
a_0+xf(x)+e^x-\frac{1}{x}\left(e^x-1\right)$$
or
$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{1-x}+\frac{e^x}{1-x}-\frac{e^x-1}{x(1-x)}$$
since $a_0=0$
$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1-x}-\frac{e^x-1}{x(1-x)}=\frac{1}{(1-x)x}-\frac{e^x}{x}=\\
\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}x^n - \sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}\color{red}{\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right)}x^{n}$$
as a result
$$a_n=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}, n\geq1$$

Comment: I don't know what the down-voter was up to, but by all means this is a combinatorial proof!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but usually your kind of proof is considered to be an algebraic one, whereas a combinatoric proof takes a set with known cardinality and constructs a *bijection* with another set showing the wanted formula or binomial identity.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer or you assume that for a set of size $n$ the number of favourable cases is $a_n$ and then try to derive the recurrence for $n+1$ from $n$. And after, solve the recurrence with generating functions. A technique very often used in enumerative combinatorics.

Comment: No doubt, this technique is great and I also appreciate it and use it often. The point is, this type of proof is usually not denoted as combinatorial proof. We find for instance in R. P. Stanleys *Enumerative Combinatorics* in the introductory chapter *How to Count*: A proof that shows that a certain set $S$ has a certain number $m$ of elements by constructing an explicit bijection between $S$ and some other set that is known to have $m$ elements is called a *combinatorial proof* or *bijective proof*. - As we can see the key term denoting a combinatorial proof is bijection.